Subset Sum variation where $x_i \in \{-1,1\}$ instead of $x_i \in \{0,1\}$
Consider the subset sum problem: for $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ let $S \in \mathbb{N}^n$ with $s_i \leq 2^m$. The Subset Sum Problem asks for a given $T_S \in \mathbb{N}$ whether exists $x \in \{0,1\}^n$ with $x^T \cdot S = T_S$. Assuming that the numbers $s_i$ are small enough the dynamical programming (DP) algorithm offers a solution to this problem. The DP algorithm basically computes all the possible sums that can be obtained with the elements in $S$.
question
Consider the following generalization:
$$
\exists^? x \in \{-1,1\}^n \hspace{0.5cm} \text{with} \hspace{0.5cm} x^T \cdot S = T_S
$$
Can this problem be solved with DP algorithm ? I am thinking of some algorithm on the following lines: let $\{T_1, ..., T_q\}$ be all the sums that can be obtained with elements from $S$. Then all possible values of $x^T\cdot S$ with $x_i \in \{-1,1\}$ are in the set $\mathcal{B} = \{2\cdot T_i - S^T\cdot 1_{n \times 1} | i \in \{1, ..., q\}\}$.
Proof
Let $A \in \mathcal{A} = \{x^T \cdot S | x \in \{-1,1\}^n\}$, then $A = x^T\cdot S = x_1^T \cdot S - x_2^T \cdot S \in \mathcal{B}$ where $x_1, x_2 \in \{0,1\}^n $ with $x_1 + x_2 = 1_{n \times 1}$. Then $x_1^T\cdot S + x_2^T \cdot S = 1_{n \times 1}^T \cdot S$ It follows that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$.
Edit
On the other hand, let $B \in \mathcal{B}$ with $B = 2\cdot T_i - S^T \cdot 1_{n\times 1} = T_i - (S^T\cdot 1_{n \times 1} - T_i) = x_1^T\cdot S - (S^T \cdot 1_{n \times 1} - S^T \cdot x_1) = x_1^T\cdot S - S^T \cdot x_2$ with $x_1, x_2 \in \{0,1\}^n$ and $x_1 + x_2 = 1_{n \times 1}$
Is my approach and understanding correct?

To give this an analogous interpretation as the usual subset sum problem: Given a set of positive integers $S'$, is there a subset $S'$ whose sum exceeds the sum of all remaining elements by $T$? (In particular, the case $T=0$ is the partition problem.)

$x$ is a vector, $T$ is a number, what does $x^T$ mean?

@GerryMyerson: $x$ transpose, but I can see your complaint about confusion of notation

@Semiclassical exactly! Is my solution ok though?

So, please change the notation.

@GerryMyerson I changed the text a little bit, but not too much, since what I used is basically standard notation. The context eliminates the confusion for pretty much any reader ... (PS: downvoting and request to close on these grounds seems a little strange to me to me honest! )

Well, it got your attention, when my comment didn't. But you are still using $T$ for both a number and the transpose operator, and you've introduced an inexplicable $T_S$. You have also had nothing to say about an answer that was posted two days ago. This is not good enough.

@gerryMyerson Is it good enough now? :)

Much better. "The DP algorithm basically computes all the possible sums that can be obtained with the elements in $S$." Well, $S$ is a finite vector, and ${-1,1}^n$ is a finite set, so any algorithm that computes all the possible values of $x^tS$ will solve the problem, right?

If $x^T \cdot S = T$ in your generalized problem, then $\frac{x+1_{n \times 1}}{2}$ changes all the $-1$s into $0$s and $\frac{(x+1_{n \times 1})^T \cdot S}{2} = \frac{T+M}{2}$ where $M$ is the sum of all the $s_i$. So solve the regular subset sum for $S$ and $\frac{T+M}{2}$ and then just change all the $0$s into $-1$s. You should also be able to change any algorithm for subset sum to do this more directly instead of an extra step like this if you want to.

So for $x \in {-1,1}^n$ your proposal actually is to change the problem $S^T\cdot x = T_S$ into $2\cdot S^T\cdot \left(\frac{x + 1_{n \times 1}}{2} \right) = T_S + S^T\cdot 1_{n \times 1}$ then denote $y = \frac{x + 1_{n \times 1}}{2}  \in {0,1}^n $. As such one solves $2 \cdot S^T \cdot y = T_S + S^T\cdot 1_{n \times 1}$ with any SSP algorithm. Right?

@CMarius Yes, that's right.

@CMarius One more thing. If $T_S+S^T\cdot 1_{n\times 1}$ isn't divisible by $2$, then you already know that there is no solution. Maybe that was already obvious but wanted to say it, just in case.
